# **Not so serious** Do examples of writing ' $limit_{n\rightarrow \infty}$' for limit notation exist?

Tags: notation

On a matchmaking TV show, a man who claimed to have earned a master's degree in mathematics in the U.S. wrote a few formulas like this, and they made me quite puzzled.
Here are his formulas:

$P(\text{Mr(s).right})=0\\ P(\text{Falling in love})=\Pi_{i=1}^{n}P_1P_2\dots P_n\\
limit_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(\text{Falling in love})=0$

These formulas indicate some of his personal thoughts towards marriage. But I am more concerned with the question of whether a field with such a notation as 'limit'(but not **$\lim$**) really exists.

Comment: Well, it's hard to be sure what was intended but I suppose it was some statement like "the number of separate events which need to go right in order to Fall In Love is so great that the whole thing is impossible".  Clearly there is no intent to write proper mathematics here...but, even so, I don't think it's so strange to write "limit" instead of $\lim$.  Presumably this was intended for a general audience, after all.

Comment: Thats non sense actually.

Comment: A more interesting approach as an optimal stopping issue [here](https://www.98online.com/2020/02/17/calculate-your-exact-chance-of-falling-in-love/)

Comment: $limit_{n\to \infty} a_n$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ are exactly the same thing.